# Confusion with class and instance variable creations

Tags: ruby

I was playing with the local,class variable and instance variable creation inside the `class` block as below. But I found something which I failed to explain myself. My confusion has been posted between the two codes below.

```
class Foo
def self.show
@@X = 10 if true
p "hi",@@X.object_id,x.object_id
end
end
#=> nil
Foo.show
#NameError: undefined local variable or method `x' for Foo:Class
#   from (irb):4:in `show'
#   from (irb):7
#   from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

The above erros is expected. But in the below code I have assigned the class variable `@@X` to `10`. But in the `p` statement I used instance variable `@X`.Why did the error not throw up like the above code ?

```
class Foo
def self.show
@@X = 10 if true
p "hi",@X.object_id
end
end
#=> nil
Foo.show
"hi"
4
#=> ["hi", 4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of [everything is object](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/about/) and no explicit variable declaration is required in Ruby, you code

```
p @X.object_id
```

silently introduces an instance variable `@X` (`@X.nil? == true`). You can see this magic in `irb`:

```
~ irb
> p @x.object_id
# 8
# ⇒ 8
```

Comment: Humm nice, then why it is not the case with `p x.object_id` ?

Comment: Local variables are simply references to objects. They persist within the scope they were declared. Since there is no local variable declared, ruby tries even to treat `x` as method of a class `Foo` (see _“or **method** ‘x’ for Foo:Class”_ in error message?) Since neither succeeded, it throws an error.